# Xamarin USB media detection broadcastreceiver OnReceive not firing

Tags: android, xamarin, usb, usb-drive

I would like to detect if an usb pendrive is attached to my android device. I have look many examples, tried many solutions without succes. Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true, Permission = "android.permission.USB_PERMISSION")]
[IntentFilter(new[] { UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached, UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceDetached })]

public class UsbAttachReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public event EventHandler UsbDeviceAttached;
    public event EventHandler UsbDeviceDetached;

    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Action.Equals(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceDetached)) UsbDeviceDetached?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        if (intent.Action.Equals(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached)) UsbDeviceAttached?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());           
    }
}
```

In activity OnCreate:

```
usbAttachReceiver = new UsbAttachReceiver();
```

In activity OnResume:

```
RegisterReceiver(usbAttachReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ActionUsbDeviceAttached));
```

In activity OnPause:

```
UnregisterReceiver(usbAttachReceiver);
```

Broadcastreceiver OnReceive method is never reached. What should be the problem? Thank for your help!